# Highlight a textbox with red border when it is required

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, validation

I'm using css to highlight a textbox with red border when it is required

```css
.garbage[style*=inline] + input,
.garbage[style*=inline] + select,
.garbage[style*=inline] + textarea {
    background-color: #ffcccc;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="Txt_fullname" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"  class="garbage" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="submit" Display="Dynamic">Type this field please.</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                
<asp:TextBox   ID="Txt_fullname" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                                
<asp:Button ID="Btn_submit" runat="server"  Text="submit form" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="submit" 
                                   onclick="Btn_submit_Click"  />
```

the problem is the css not apply until I click on the textbox

Comment: I think that's to do with renderer optimisation.

Comment: try from this link it may helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/a/21239351/2798643

Comment: Hi, Were you able to solve this issue? I am facing this issue, but only in IE, it's working fine on Chrome. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS :

```
:required {
  border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I use asp:RequiredFieldValidator control that not add required attribute to input

Comment: you can try to add :CssClass="error" to your asp:RequiredFieldValidator
Then add css:
error{
  border-color: red;
}

Answer (score 0):

If you put `required` attribute on one radio button (or any combination), that particular **group of radio buttons** will be required.

On checkboxes, makes each individual checkbox required (to be checked).

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" required="">
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" required="required">
```

**CSS**

```
:required{
    border-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: I use asp:RequiredFieldValidator control that not add required attribute to input

Comment: Could u please share ur page source? the HTML output